# Alternatives to react-spring-3d-carousel

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-spring

Guys I need to implement a 3-d carousel for my displaying the images. For this I implemented a library called react-spring-3d-carousel. But I'm having some problems with it because first of all its really slow and it doesn't have a built in support for dragging the images so that they can slide. I've searched all over the internet looking for alternatives to it but to not much avail. It would be great if stackoverflow might help as it was kind of a last resort. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I used this carousel you can adjust the scrolling speed and put it in autoplay : `npm install 3d-react-carousal`

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.